# mysql Calculation of Time Difference for Unique User Listing

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following situation

1. User visits the site from google and we record this info in database table "visitSearchEngine". If user registers then his status is active i.e. 1 and if he doesn't then his status becomes inactive i.e. 0 .  So, I am in need of a query where..   If user visits the site and doesn't register in 10 minutes then list out those users.

   I have written a following query but it's not working

   ```
   select distinct(users) , avisitedDate from visitSearchEngine vs
   WHERE vs.users!=' ' 
   AND vs.status='0' 
   AND hitType='googleIdentified'
   AND avisitedDate>'2012-12-06' 
   AND minute(timediff(now(),avisitedDate))>=10
   AND minute(timediff(now(),avisitedDate))<11

   //avisitedDate is Today's date.
   ```

I want to calculate the difference between currentTime and visitedDate and if it's 10 minutes then list out those users.

Thanks,

Comment: What error are you getting, or you are not getting the expected results

Comment: is `avisitedDate` a `DATE` or a `DATETIME` column? Or a `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: Is column `users` unique? Or there are two or more rows for the same user?

Comment: @SashiKant.... I am not getting the expected result

Comment: @ypercube... It is a datetime

Comment: @ypercuber... I used distinct(users) for this purpose..

Comment: So, what should happen if a user has `status=0` in one row and `=1` in another? Does the latest status matter? Or if it has at least one as `1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is `time_to_sec`:

```
select distinct(users) , avisitedDate from visitSearchEngine vs
WHERE vs.users!=' ' 
AND vs.status='0' 
AND hitType='googleIdentified'
AND avisitedDate>'2012-12-06' 
AND time_to_sec(timediff(now(),avisitedDate))>=10*60
AND time_to_sec(timediff(now(),avisitedDate))<11*60
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
select distinct(users) , avisitedDate from visitSearchEngine vs
WHERE vs.users!=' ' 
AND vs.status='0' 
AND hitType='googleIdentified'
AND DATE(avisitedDate)>'2012-12-06' 
AND minute(timediff(now(),avisitedDate))>=10
AND minute(timediff(now(),avisitedDate))<11
```

Comment: I am only confused about this line...   AND minute(timediff(now(),avisitedDate))>=10
AND minute(timediff(now(),avisitedDate))<11

Is it correct line to find the 10 mins difference between currentTime and visitedTime?

Comment: What I am thinking is MINUTE() doesn't return the given value in minutes: it returns only the minutes part of the time??

Comment: No it doesn't... When I ran this query.. it showed me the users from 2012-12-06 08:39:26.......  But now the time here is  14:00:00 ....  so what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Got the Answer, used time_to_Sec...  and it displayed..

```
select distinct(users) , avisitedDate from visitSearchEngine vs
WHERE vs.users!=' ' 
AND vs.status='0' 
AND hitType='googleIdentified'
AND DATE(avisitedDate)>'2012-12-06' 
AND ((time_to_Sec(timediff(now(),avisitedDate)))/60)>=5
AND ((time_to_Sec(timediff(now(),avisitedDate)))/60)<6
```

Comment: Just curious . . . Is there a reason you didn't get this from my answer?